HackerRank Bill division: Time limit exceeded in Bash
I'm playing on HackerRank, and I'd like to solve the Bill division exercise in BASH. It is a really simple problem, I've already solved it in multiple languages.
My initial Bash solution was this:
#!/bin/bash

billDivision() {
    local n="${1}"
    local k="${2}"
    local b_charged="${3}"
    shift 3
    local bills=( "${@}" )
    
    (( b_actual = -bills[ k ] ))
    for bill in "${bills[@]}"; do
        (( b_actual += bill ))
    done
    (( b_actual /= 2 ))
    (( b_overcharge = b_charged - b_actual ))
    if(( b_overcharge <= 0 )); then
        echo "Bon Appetit"
    else
        echo "${b_overcharge}"
    fi
}

read nk
n="$( echo "${nk}" | cut -d " " -f 1 )"
k="$( echo "${nk}" | cut -d " " -f 2 )"
read ar
IFS=" "; read -ra arr <<< "${ar}"
read b
result="$( billDivision "${n}" "${k}" "${b}" "${arr[@]}" )"
echo "${result}"

It works for all tests except 4 and 5, which fail with Time limit exceeded.
I know that Bash uses sparse arrays with some linked-list-like internal representation that is not optimal for speed of access.
So I thought, the reason must be that the array is too long in these cases. I checked one of them, and it confirms my assumption.
Therefore, I tried to get rid of the array by iterating over the elements of a space separated string. I even inlined the function:
#!/bin/bash

read nk
n="$( echo "${nk}" | cut -d " " -f 1 )"
k="$( echo "${nk}" | cut -d " " -f 2 )"
read bills
read b_charged

(( counter = 0 ))
for bill in ${bills}; do
    if(( counter++ != k )); then
        (( b_actual += bill ))
    fi
done
(( b_actual /= 2 ))
(( b_overcharge = b_charged - b_actual ))
if(( b_overcharge <= 0 )); then
    echo "Bon Appetit"
else
    echo "${b_overcharge}"
fi

I got the same result, time limit exceeded in test cases 4 and 5.
What is the trick to make Bash process long lists faster?
Or fast enough for HackerRank?

cut is not a bash builtin and echo may or may not be a bash builtin. If you can call cut (a mandatory POSIX tool) from bash then presumably you can call awk (another mandatory POSIX tool) from bash and then you can write the whole thing in awk and it'll be orders of magnitude faster than your current script, and be the way you'd REALLY solve this problem using bash - just have bash call awk to do the work. Are you interested in a solution like that?

can't help with the main problem but note that echo a b | read n k ;echo $n " xxx " $k produces a xxx b. Good luck.

@EdMorton Good point, I wrote a version with awk. I just don't know whether it is cheating. After all, you may even call Python from Bash, and I would definitely not consider that a Bash solution. But awk is not choosable as a language, so that may be where I pull the boundary.

The difference between calling python from bash and calling awk from bash is that python is not a mandatory POSIX tool and so YMMV when trying to run such a solution on any given Unix box while awk is a mandatory POSIX tool and so will be present on every Unix box that bash is present on. Most people when they ask for a bash solution are not asking for a solution that uses only bash builtins, they're asking for a solution using bash plus mandatory POSIX tools. If you can use cut then I expect you can use awk and then you don't need all the other bash calculation code.

consider updating the question with a couple sample runs, showing all variable/value pairs, the (correct/wrong) results and for the failed sample(s) the complete error message and (correct) expected results

@markp-fuso There is no logic error in my code, it just wasn't fast enough. The only test cases where it failed were the ones with 100000-element lists, and since I had to pay with "hackos" or whatever for them, I think it would not be fair to publish them. The error message did not contain any more details than my quotation.

You're wasting time adding up bills. This should work fine:
read n k
read -a bill
read charged
IFS=+
actual=$(((${bill[*]}-bill[k])/2))
if ((charged == actual)); then
  echo Bon Appetit
else
  echo $((charged-actual))
fi


Thanks, it works - usually. (First test 5 succeeded and 4 failed although both contain 100000 elements, then I clicked the button again without changing the code, and both succeeded. Performance tests are not deterministic.)

@z32a7ul wasn't the starting point of your question a script that "usually" worked but you wanted something that always worked?

@EdMorton If it's accepted a single time, then I consider it good enough. I had failed first and succeeded the second time without changing anything. What if the "luck factor" helped me the first time? I would not run it the second time, but accept the solution. It is on the edge, and I don't have control over the environment, and the time limit is defined as "1 second".

The subsequent runs are probably succeeding due to caching rather than luck.
